# How to remove visual studio curly braces lines

Tags: visual-studio

visual studio shows me lines which stretch between curly braces from top to bottom.
Any idea how do I remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options->"Text Editor"->General -> and there remove the checkbox on "Show structure guide lines"